# Dynamic order of columns in a primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, facelets

I have a `datatable` of which i need to show specific columns for each user with specific order e.g column1,column25,column13,etc..

What do you recommend as an implementation for this, should i use datatable binding; like creating `htmldatatable`, and give it to JSF page to render it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is here :

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columns.xhtml

Comment: I have a another question, how can i access property of property eg: person.adress.city ?

Comment: You mean how to access an object inside another object ?

Comment: exactly, how do you do that ?

Comment: Open a new question i will answer to you. That can be help someone else.